# Linking to Supplemental Material on arXiv (empirical data, code, etc)

Tags: releasing-data, open-access

In Dec'20 the open access pre-print service, arXiv, introduced the ability to include a [link to code](https://blog.arxiv.org/2020/12/10/instant-access-to-code-for-any-arxiv-paper/) in the metadata for a preprint. Certainly a step in the right direction. However, with a little tweak it could be described as a link to 'supplemental material' more generally, not just code. Then it could be used to link to empirical data, video material, etc. as well.

My question: Where can I raise discussion about an arXiv feature like this with those who determine arXiv policies? After extensive searching I cannot find anywhere for feature requests or public discussion about arXiv facilities or policies.

Failing that, please feel free to discuss the merit of my proposal here.

Obviously, a link can be included in the article itself, but the facility to include a link or links in the top level metadata emphasizes the importance of supporting material. arXiv already had a facility for uploading [ancillary files](https://arxiv.org/help/ancillary_files), but this was not intended for large datasets, for which a facility to add a hyperlink would seem far more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found that arXiv does have an interface for feature requests:
https://arxiv-org.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/1

It's not for public discussion, but it's better than nothing.